# How to call C++/CX code from pure C++ class in DirectXXaml Project?

Tags: c++, c++-cx

I have a DirectXXaml Project and code of my game written in pure C++ I need to open a file in one of my classes. How can I do it?

I thought I have to use `#pragma managed` but no result.

Previously I had this code:

```
void DataLoader::load(std::string const& file) {
    std::ifstream fileStream(file.c_str(), ios::binary);

    fileStream.seekg(0, ios::end);
    _dataSize = fileStream.tellg(); 
    fileStream.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> buffer(_dataSize);
    fileStream.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size());

    _data = new ByteArray(buffer);

    fileStream.close();

    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event::COMPLETE));
}
```

How can I use C++/CX here?

Comment: WARNING: using the narrow constructor for an `ifstream` is not recommended on windows as it uses the ANSI code page to open the file. If the path contains characters that cannot be represented in that code page the open will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use C++/CX you need to have the /ZW flag turned on for the project you are building. You can find this setting under Project Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Consume Windows Runtime Extension. Se this to 'Yes' if it isn't already.

Once this flag is turned on you should be able to call into C++/CX Windows Runtime APIs from your existing C++ code.

Here is a blog post I wrote on this topic a while ago, you may run into situations where you only want to include the /ZW flag for some files in your project, this can be done: http://robwirving.com/2013/10/01/windows-phone-8-native-dev-tip-hack-your-vcxproj-file-to-selectively-include-the-winrt-extensions/

Comment: Please copy the relevant portions from your blog post into the answer, links to external sites may go inactive (even your blog) and thus the full value of the answer is lost.

Comment: I did. The most important thing is to just set the Consume Windows Runtime Extension flag as I noted in my answer. The blog post just contains additional info that may be useful.